# Rails - raise exception in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

Within my form for the model `Portfolio`, I have the following field:

```
<%= f.number_field(:p_return, id:"return_number") %>
```

I want to validate if the number inputed is within a range `[0..max_return]`, where `max_return` is another field of `Portfolio`. If the number is not in this range, I want to return an exception or error to the user.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Add validation to your Portfolio model use [validates_numericality_of](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods/validates_numericality_of) helper or write custom validator for your validation case use [validates_each](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_each) helper.